# BIND9 DNS forwarding with split horizion

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, zimbra

I am trying to figure out what to do about my Zimbra server's DNS.

According the Zimrba wiki they recommend that I install a copy of something like BIND on the server itself so Zimbra can handle the internal queries made by postfix.

So I went and install BIND9 and got my zone running, the zone is `solignis.com`. Now here is where it get confusing.

I already have a BIND9 server running on my network that is responsible for the same domain `solignis.com`. But that server is the "network" DNS the other one on Zimbra is for Zimbra ONLY.

But when I go the Zimbra host and try to ping the other server (NS01) it says its an `unknown host`. even though I have forwarding enabled to the main DNS server. Follow me?

So I have a multi part question.

1. Is the best way to setup DNS for my needs (as per Zimbra)?
2. Assuming #1 is true, is there a way to force BIND to forward queries
   for a domain its responsible for to another server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a dedicated DNS Server for zimbra, you can user your existing network DNS, add zimbra entries there and make your zimbra server use that DNS server.
As a workaround to that DNS issue, it happens to me also, when no DNS server is available, to use /etc/hosts file to resolve zimbra servers hostnames internally.

Comment: I see so that is why the hostfile is supposed to be set before installing Zimbra. Because it would not allow me install until it was setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the Zimbra box as a nameserver for itself you should use it as a secondary DNS to your existing server.

Comment: Okay that is what I originally had and it worked fine. But I kept having some feeling that it should have been different. The other question is then "who wrote the Zimbra wiki tutorial" because it is partly wrong. Anyhow thanks.